# Shall the overriding method in Son be able to call the overridden method of Father template class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overriding

I have defined a template class with a virtual method:

```
template<class T> 
class Father{
   public:
   virtual void foo(int a);
 }
```

I have then defined a class, inheriting from the template class, and overriding its method:

```
class Son: public Father<int>{
  public:
  virtual void foo(int a);
}
```

Shall the overriding method in Son be able to call the overridden method of Father?

I tried the 3 following implementations but none seems to compile:

1) In Son.cpp

```
void Son::foo(int a){
     Father::foo(a);      
}
```

2) In Son.cpp:

```
   void Son::foo(int a){
     ::foo(a);      
    }
```

3) In Son.h

```
 using Father::foo;
 virtual void foo(int a);
```

In Son.cpp

```
  void Son::foo(int a){
     Father::foo(a);      
    }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your first attempt compiles: [wandbox link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RXzoLsy8AUVJjw8p)

Comment: In truth , I just found out that the following option 4 is compiling:                                                                                                             void Son::foo(int a){
      Father<int>::foo(a);      
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just solved this: the answer seems to be YES and the following code is compiling:

```
void Son::foo(int a){
     Father<int>::foo(a);      
}
```